# SQL Error - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a script/SP to extract data from a table and and send an email in HTML format with the data included in the email.  I have the following written but get the above error but not entirely sure where to 'fix' the subquery.  The query at the moment is:
    DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

```
SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Ad Groups and Users</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>AD Group Name</th><th>Number of Users</th>' +
        CAST    ( 
             (SELECT        Group_Name,
                                    COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Users'
                        FROM        TABLE
                        WHERE       Group_Name IN   (
                                                    'PA_OptiTime',
                                                    'PA_P6',
                                                    'PA65_BIW',
                                                    'PA65_CAFM',
                                                    'PA65_CoinsOA',
                                                    'PA65_ConquestQ',
                                                    'PA65_Desktop_Osborne',
                                                    'PA65_MicrosoftAccess',
                                                    'PA65_MicrosoftOfficeStandard',
                                                    'PA65_MicrosoftOneNote',
                                                    'PA65_MicrosoftProject',
                                                    'PA65_MicrosoftVisio',
                                                    'PA65_MicrosoftVisioViewer',
                                                    'PA65_XStandard',
                                                    'SA65_AdobeCSSuite',
                                                    'SA65_AdobeProfessional',
                                                    'SA65_AdobeReader',
                                                    'SA65_AdobeStandard',
                                                    'SA65_AstaPowerproject',
                                                    'SA65_BentleyProjectwise',
                                                    'SA65_BravaReader',
                                                    'SA65_BravaViewer',
                                                    'SA65_CoinsPlus',
                                                    'SA65_GemSafe',
                                                    'SA65_GoogleEarth',
                                                    'SA65_NavisworksFreedomViewer',
                                                    'SA65_NRG',
                                                    'SA65_Offline',
                                                    'SA65_PDFEditor',
                                                    'SA65_PolycomCMADesktop',
                                                    'SA65_PrimaveraP6',
                                                    'SA65_SelectHR',
                                                    'SA65_ShareRegister',
                                                    'SA65_SketchUp',
                                                    'SA65_Xpress3DViewer'
                                                    )
                        GROUP BY Group_Name
                    ) 
                        AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
                ) +
    N'</table>' ;

--create full body text
DECLARE @BodyText varchar(255)
DECLARE @SubjectText varchar(255)

SELECT @SubjectText = 'Test Email'

SELECT @BodyText = @tableHTML 

--send message
EXEC EXSP_SendSMTPMailCDO 
    @To='email@work.com', 
    @Subject = @SubjectText,
    @Body = @BodyText,
    --@HTMLFormat = 0,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @From = 'email@work.com',
    @Server = 'smtprelay'

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to cast a sub query which returns two columns to an NVARCHAR. Sql Server is not going to understand how to aggregate two columns into a single text field and is going to throw the error you received.

```
CAST    ((SELECT Group_Name,
                 COUNT(*) AS 'Number of Users'
                 FROM        TABLE
                 WHERE       Group_Name IN   (
                                                'PA_OptiTime'                                                    
                                                )
                    GROUP BY Group_Name
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

EDIT: Even reducing the sub query to return a single column won't work. The issue is it looks like you are attempting to append a line of XML for each group. So while the original error is produced by attempting to cast multiple columns in SQL, fixing that problem won't produce a query which appends a line of XML for each group.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The data I am obtaining is the number of users per group and I want to email ths straight out to the appropriate people...  been trying a few ways, but cannot get anything to work...  Any suggestions at all?

Comment: I got there in the end - resolution was: